# Fixed table layout not filling specified table width

Tags: html, css

I am using `display:table` with fixed table layout to show some data in a web app.

The table width is set to 100%. There are two columns, and I am explicitly setting a width on the second column. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout), after the column widths are calculated, "if the table is wider than the columns, the extra space should be distributed over the columns."

However this does not seem to be working as expected when the second column is an `input` element. In this case, the second column retains the specified width and the first column takes 50% of the table. The extra space is **not** distributed over the columns, and thus the table does not fill the available width.

Here's an example; first test works as expected, second one doesn't:

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>Test 1 -- works as expected</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Label</div>
  <div class="cell right">Field</div>
</div>

<p>Test 2 -- table does not fill available width</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Label</div>
  <input class="cell right" type="text" value="Text input" />
</div>
```

Am I missing something? Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use table for tabular data, don't go with the rules of completely ignoring the tables, ignore it for layout purpose not for tabular data, what you doing is incorrect.

Comment: Doesn't look like tabular data to me, but I could be wrong. Maybe it is tabular data that happens to be editable, instead of a form that is presented like a table.

Comment: @BoltClock still, its incorrect, would rather use ul li with nested label and input tags both floated to the left and clearing each of the li using clearfix

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you for your opinion but that does not answer the question.

Comment: @Grodriguez It was actually not an answer, it was a suggestion :) or better say standards

Comment: @Mr.Alien Which standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. The behavior you're observing is consistent across browsers, but I can't find anything in the spec that alludes to this behavior. I thought it might have something to do with replaced elements, but in fact the spec [says otherwise](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display):

> Replaced elements with these 'display' values are treated as their given display types during layout. For example, an image that is set to 'display: table-cell' will fill the available cell space, and its dimensions might contribute towards the table sizing algorithms, as with an ordinary cell.

So it looks like there shouldn't be any difference in how the table is rendered. Honestly, I don't know. I could go so far as to say that *every* browser is getting tripped up by the presence of replaced elements, as the same behavior occurs when you use an `img` in lieu of an `input`, but I don't have enough proof to say for certain whether or not this behavior is expected.

Due to the nature of replaced elements, I don't think there is a way to fix this using just CSS. The only alternative that I can think of is to make that cell a non-replaced element such as a `div` in your first test case, and put the `input` in the non-replaced element.

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.right {
  width: 200px;
}
.right input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Label</div>
  <div class="cell right">Field</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Label</div>
  <div class="cell right"><input type="text" value="Text input" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am accepting this because it confirms my suspicion that my approach *should* work according to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7urnt4v/).

In the second row, instead of

```
<input class="cell right" type="text" value="Text input" />
```

do

```
<div class="cell right"><input type="text" value="Text input" style="width: 98%;"/></div>
```

And change the CSS:

```
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I can work around this with an extra div. But I would like to know why the layout algorithm is not working as expected when using an input element directly. Also I would rather avoid adding extra elements to the markup. A CSS-only solution would be welcome.